# (Postgres) Index(es) for User Selected Filtering Options

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Say I have a table with many columns, and a UI that allows users to select different filtering options on several of those columns. Let's say there's five filter options, for the sake of this question.

The filter options in the UI allow a user to select from a couple values for each column (imagine dropdowns), but if a user selects nothing for that column, then there will be *no* `WHERE` condition on that column. In other words, if the user selects no filters at all, we want all of the rows. If they only select a value for column A, there will be no `WHERE` condition on columns B, C, D, or E. Etc.

There are a couple `WHERE` conditions that the query will always include (such as a `user_id`), and the results will be sorted (by a `created_at` column) and paginated (using a `LIMIT` and a front-end supplied "since" or "before" value to filter the `created_at` column).

So, the question is: what's the best way to index this? Something like an index on `(user_id, created_at)` would help for the columns that the query always includes, paginating, and sorting. But, what about the other columns? Since there won't always be a `WHERE` condition on those columns, will a single index on all 7 columns (`user_id`, `created_at`, and the five columns a user can filter on) work? From my testing, it seems postgres can skip over columns in composite indexes if there's no `WHERE` clause on them (ex: index on `(a,b,c)` and a query on only `a` and `c` can still use the index), but I don't know if there's a limit to its ability to do so, or any gotchyas.

Or would it make more sense to have indexes on the individual columns and allow postgres to determine when it should use a `BitmapAnd` on the indexes? If I go the individual index route, would it make sense to include some other columns in these individual indexes? For example, the columns that are always included in the query (ie, `user_id`)? So I'd have a index like `(user_id,A)`, and `(user_id,B)`, etc?

Or maybe some hybrid approach? A single index on `user_id`, `created_at`, and one or two of the most used filters, and then individual indexes for the other columns?

Thanks! =)

Comment: Log the queries and build your indexes based on how the table's typically accessed. Log, reproduce, see if you can improve those with indexes, test it, add it, log again. You can add non-key columns into the index with `include` clause if they are always fetched but never filtered on. You can also `cluster` the table to be physically written in a way that follows the "main, most useful" index.